# Django Forms created from Model with overfull Queryset Output

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a ModelForm for my Model Class "Asset" in Django 3

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Asset(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manufacturer = models.ManyToManyField(Manufacturer)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I managed to create a Form via the following code

```
from django import forms
from .models import Manufacturer

class AssetForm(forms.Form):
    serial = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    manufacturer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all().values('name'))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.TextInput()
    status = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The querySet results in a dropdown being filled out with either "{'name':'Apple'}" or "('Apple',)" depending on using values or values_list respectively. How can I just display the name itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following method to the model fixes the problem:

```
    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This will return the name and only the name to the queryset.